# Latex create a function to wrap code

Tags: formatting, code

I have the following to highlight code:

```
\begin{minted}{python}
def foo():

\end{minted}
```

However, typing out `\begin{minted}{python}` is quite tedious.

I want to convert it something like the following:

```
\code
def foo();

\end
```

What't the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/can-i-print-only-some-functions-with-minted/55333#55333

Comment: Please, see this answer by @egreg:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269036/starting-environment-with-beginenv-or-with-env
It is explained why the use of environments is always preferred with respect to what you want to do.

Comment: Use an editor with auto-completion.  That is much better than building a house of cards of macros on top of your document.